# Alternating the types of views displayed in a ViewPager

Tags: android

I'm building a magazine e-reader app, using a viewpager as the primary navigational element. Article objects are deserialized (from data received from a REST web service), and used to inflate "cover pages" that are inflated by the pager adapter, which the user "flips through".

This all works perfectly using a PagerAdapter with an instantiateItem method like this (with an ArrayList of articles passed to the adapter's constructor):

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View arg0, int position) {

    final Article s = toShow.get(position);

    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.previewpage, null);

    TextView hl = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.coverHl);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.coverImg);

            ....

    hl.setText(s.title);
    img.setImageBitmap(s.image);
```

My issue is that, at every 6th position, I'd like to inflate a different view to show an ad. At the moment, I have an if statement added to the top of this method like :

```
if ((position != 0) && (position%6 == 0)){
```

after which I inflate the other view and place the appropriate ad on it. However, this leads to numerous complications: On the next view, I can no longer say toShow.get(position) because doing so skips one of the articles in the array (the one at the position at which the ad was shown). So, I created an `int adsShown`, which gets incremented every time an ad is shown, and call `final Article s = toShow.get(position - adsShown)`. But when I do that, if the user flips back through the viewpager, an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error is shown because it position-adsshown is -1.

I know I can figure out workarounds for these issues, but I'm questioning whether there is a simpler way to handle this task in the first place.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the correct position using something like this:

```
// check if position > 0 to make sure we don't start with an ad
if(position > 0 && position%6 == 0) {
  // get ad view here
else {
  int index = position - (int)Math.floor(position/6);
  final Article s = toShow.get(index);
  ...
}
```

Also remember that your `getCount` will have to return the number of articles plus the number of ads or else it will not show all the articles you have in your array.